# How to fix a DirectoryNotFoundException?

Tags: c#, wpf, directory

I'm trying to overlay a local image on to a video feed from a Kinect sensor but when I overlay the image I get a `DirectoryNotFoundException` even though the image directory seems to be correct.Does anyone have an explanation as to why I could be getting this error or how to fix it?

Throws the DirectoryNotFoundException at this line of code:

```
drawingContext.DrawImage(overlayImage, new Rect(12, 12, overlayImage.Width, overlayImage.Height));
```

The complete method below is taking a video feed from a Kinect sensor and overlaying an image to the video feed. The program crashes when I use the code to draw the overlay but working fine without it.

```
void myKinect_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
    {
        if (colorFrame == null) return;
        byte[] colorData = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];
        colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorData);
        KinectVideo.Source = BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96,
                PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel);

        //drawing image overlay to video feed
        var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
        drawingContext.DrawImage(BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel), 
                new Rect(new Size(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height)));
        var overlayImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/boxbag.png", UriKind.Relative));
        //Error thrown here -->
        drawingContext.DrawImage(overlayImage, new Rect(12, 12, overlayImage.Width, overlayImage.Height));
        drawingContext.Close();
        var mergedImage = new RenderTargetBitmap(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        mergedImage.Render(drawingVisual);
        KinectVideo.Source = mergedImage;
    }
}
```

This is the complete error as shown in Visual Studio, what I understand from the error is that theimage is not present in the folder, but doesn't make sense as the image is stored in a folder named `Images` in the project solution.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Brian Smith\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\KinectKickboxingBVversion1\KinectKickboxingBVversion1\bin\x86\Debug\Images\boxbag.png'
```

.

This is the full path to the image according to VS:

```
C:\Users\Brian Smith\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\KinectKickboxingBVversion1\KinectKickboxingBVversion1\Images\boxbag.png
```

Comment: Read the path it's complaining about.  Your current directory is not what you think it is.

Comment: I just looked at the error path and the actual..The difference in the actual path and VS is extra `\bin\x86\Debug` .How do I change the image location to this path instead?

Comment: Don't do that.  You should embed the image in your application.  Otherwise, it won't be able to run from any other directory.

Comment: How do I embed the image @SLaks ?

Comment: Set the Build Action to Resource, then use a Pack URI.

Comment: @Slaks cheers that worked, but when the image overlay is drawn to screen its zoomed in to much,only shows top half of image.Is there a way to adjust it so it views the complete image or do I need a smaller image dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead (may need to tweak the name of the assembly):

```
var overlayImage
  = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/KinectKickboxingBVversion1;component/Images/boxbag.png"));
```

More on [Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).